# Saving backbone model causes the ajax call to just hang

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, mongoose

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong as I've tried to debug this for awhile now. I'm creating the beginning parts of an webapp. Right now, I'm trying to save a form using backbone. I am using Node.js, Mongoose, Express, and Backbone.

Everything seems to work alright except that when I send my model back to the server, the request hangs and eventually causes a timeout. Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:[image: I tried the request twice and both time, it's hangs and then times out]

I'm not quite sure where the problem is because I'm still a newbie to this sort of stack.

Here is my Backbone view. Nothing special. It renders a form using dust. In the submit method, I am gathering all the form's data into an array and forming a new user model which I then save back to the server. Again, the server IS saving the data as I see it in the database. However, when I look in Firebug, I see that the POST request just hangs there and doesn't end (it has the spinning loading thing as if it's still waiting for a response from the server.

```
define(['dust/addUser','models/userModel'], function(AddUser, UserModel) {
    AddUser = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },
        tagName: 'div',
        id: 'addUserContainer',
        events: {
            'submit form': 'submit'
        },
        render: function() {
            $thisSelf = this.$el;
            dust.render('addUser','', function(error, output) {
                $thisSelf.append(output);
            });

            $('#wrapper').append($thisSelf);
        },
        /** 
         * @method submit
         * Capture the submit event, create a logical array of data, send to model
         */
        submit: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var dataArray = $('#addUser').serializeArray(),
                    data = _(dataArray).reduce(function(data, field) {
                        data[field.name] = field.value;
                        return data;
                    }, {});

                    var newUserModel = new UserModel(data);
                    console.log(newUserModel);
                    newUserModel.save({
                        success: function(model, response) {
                            console.log(model);
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                        error: function(model, response) {
                            console.log(model);
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    });
        },
    });
```

Here are the relevant parts to my server.js file. Here I am requiring mongoose and creating the connection.

```
var application_root = __dirname,
express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
app = express();

//database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://nodejitsu:840391d8ed69abf8583c9da46cd6a9c5@paulo.mongohq.com:10041/nodejitsudb7458111315');
```

And here is the API route I created:

```
app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
  var user;
  user = new UserModel({
    rider: req.body.rider,
    driver: req.body.driver,
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    address: req.body.address,
    city: req.body.city,
    state: req.body.state,
    zip: req.body.zip,
    startTime: req.body.startTime,
    endTime: req.body.endTime,
    officeLocation: req.body.officeLocation
  });
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      return console.log("user created.");
    } else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wasn't returning a success response. And when I did try to do that previously, I didn't realize I was also returning something already.

Here is my updated mongoose code:

```
app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
  var user;
  user = new UserModel({
    rider: req.body.rider,
    driver: req.body.driver,
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    address: req.body.address,
    city: req.body.city,
    state: req.body.state,
    zip: req.body.zip,
    startTime: req.body.startTime,
    endTime: req.body.endTime,
    officeLocation: req.body.officeLocation
  });
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.send(200, 'User saved.');
    } else {
      return res.send(500)
    }
  });
});
```